# Weird text wrap behavior in nested absolute positioned divs

Tags: html, css

consider the following code:

```html
<div id="p1" style="position: absolute">
  <div id="p2" style="position: absolute">
    <div id="c" style="max-width: 120px">
      This text should wrap when exceed 120px
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Don't ask me why both #p1 and #p2 need an absolute position, they are part of a legacy component I can't change.
I expect #c to grow with the text until it reaches the max-width of 120px. However, how you can see in the example, the text breaks at every word.

This behavior appears only if I have 2 nested parent divs with position absolute. I tried to play with properties such as white-space and word-wrap with no success.

I'm really interested in finding out why such behavior occur. Does anybody has an answer?

Comment: I can't explain to you _why_ this happens, but you can fix it by setting a `width` / `min-width` to the `#c` element. Depending on what you're doing, you can even ditch the `max-width: 120px` and replace it with `width: 120px;`

Comment: Just apply `#p1 { width: 100%; }`

Comment: @MichaelCoker _"they are part of a legacy component I can't change"_ though

Comment: Oh you don't want a fix, just an explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute positioned elements need width and height settings, otherwise they don't expand. Try to add some settings, for example this:

```css
#p1, #p2 {
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="p1" style="position: absolute">
  <div id="p2" style="position: absolute">
    <div id="c" style="max-width: 120px">
      This text should wrap when exceed 120px
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```